# What do you do when the chromedriver that matches your chrome version isn't out yet?

Tags: vba, selenium

I have a specific use case requiring me to use 'Selenium Basic' for VBA.
The versions don't match and it fails as seen in the image below:

[image]

The problem is that the chromedriver that matches the chrome installed isn't out yet.

Moreover, all other browsers except the useless I.E. have the same error, and I mean, Firefox or Opera would do of course.
Here is the error these browsers have below.

[image]

I initially believed maybe Kaspersky was at fault however its not: even off this connectivity problem persists.

I've google for exactly 65 minutes before writing this.
If you have anything of value to share, it would really help me out professionally here.

Thank you kindly,

Comment: you have the right driver installed. It needs someone to test whether this is a selenium basic problem due to it no longer being maintained - which is the problem you are seeing with FF. Can you show enough code to reproduce the error and indicate on which line the error occurs? The source of your error may lie elsewhere.

Comment: @QHarr Sure. And thank you for trying to help :-)     Option Explicit

Private browser As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub login()

    Set browser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    browser.Start
    browser.Get "spacequest.procurify.com"
    
End Sub

Comment: Which line gives the error please? Did you try with the full web address (including leading protocol http(s) etc...)

Answer (score 1):

**Chromedriver version:**

If you look at the official download site you will see the appropriate version is the Chrome version 89. This covers your version. FireFox is no longer supported and you would need to go back a long way to find a supported version and use the appropriate browser and driver.

[image]

I have tested the driver + browser combination which you show with python and it works as expected. The ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23 driver *should* cover all 89... version Chrome browser releases to date.

---

**InvalidArgumentException (Runtime error 0 SeleniumError Invalid Argument):**

With reference to the error you saw this post gives the official documentation on it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59067676

You are seeing this error because you have missed the protocol from your url.

Try the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private browser As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Public Sub login()
    Set browser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    browser.Get "https://some_safe_url_goes_here.com"
    
    Stop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, QHarr! Such a small thing I feel ashamed. Never program when you get tired in my case. Thank you again!

Comment: Check chromedriver version from the command line ==> PS C:\Users\david\appdata\Local\SeleniumBasic> .\chromeDriver -v
ChromeDriver 118.0.5993.70 (e52f33f30b91...

Comment: googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable download chrome and chromedriver here

Comment: Test chromedriver like so - Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay: DoEvents: Next i: End Sub - and - 
Sub sbChromeDriver(): Dim bt As New Selenium.ChromeDriver: bt.Start: bt.Get "https://www.google.com": sbDelay (200000): End Sub